# How to store the url in the database correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a menu in the database like everyone else:

| id | parent_id | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | clothes |
| 2 | 1 | men |
| 3 | 2 | pants |
| 3 | 1 | women |
| 4 | 3 | pants |

I'm coming `web.com/clothes/men/pants`, I catch the url in the controller:

It is very inconvenient to always collect all the URLs:

- For the menu
- To understand what category we are in in order to show the product correctly

Maybe should I immediately store the full urls in the database?

There are 1800 categories in total! And cache everything!

| id | parent_id | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | clothes |
| 2 | 1 | clothes/men |
| 3 | 2 | clothes/men/pants |
| 3 | 1 | clothes/women |
| 4 | 3 | clothes/women/pants |

Answer (score 0):

The menu is composed of heirarchial elements at different levels. Therefore, a logical approach would be to store them in separate tables depending on there level, so:

Level  1:

Clothes

Level 2:

Men

Women

Level 3:

Pants

This hybrid approach makes construction of the taxomic levels easy without the brute force of storing thousands of full url paths that will be hard to maintain.